# Table doesn't align vertically

Tags: php, html, css

So I want to do something very simple, which I can't figure out properly. I'm currently making a forum and where I normally have errors (the back end) it all works now, probably through the black magic I used ;D,

So now, the thing is: I want to show all my subcategories, so I'm using the following table:

```
<div id="content_big">
    <div class="content_top_oranje">
        <p class="koptekst">
            <?php echo 'Name';?>
        </p>
        <p style="float:left; margin-left:70%; margin-top:-30px; color:#fff; font-size:11px;font-family:Ubuntu;">
            <?php echo 'Description';?>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="content_mid">
        <?php $kop='algemeen' ;
              $query=$ db->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM ht_forum_categorien WHERE kop = ?");
              $query->bind_param('s', $kop);
              $query->execute();
              $result = $query->get_result();
              while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
        <table style="width:100%;" border="1" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <?php echo $row[ 'name']; ?>
                </td>
                <td style="margin-left:50px;">
                    <?php echo $row[ 'description]; ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <?php
              }
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

But when I use that, this is the output I get:
[image: Kinda weird table]

How is it possible that all of the rows won't vertically align? And how to solve it?

Thanks. (I'm sorry the screenshot is in dutch, but I can't change the values in the DB, since it isn't mine

Comment: I don't see you using "a table": this code generates *lots* of separate 2-column tables. Generate your rows dynamically, with the `<table>` opening and closing tags outside your generation loop.

Comment: @Oriol the code shows that's not even the case. It's simply a heading and then five tables that all happen to have a single row with two columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two fairly big problems in your code:

1. most importantly, and the problem you ran into: you're not generating a table. You're generating **lots** of tables. If you want one table, move your `<table>` and `</table>` tags outside of your loop and only generate `<tr>` with their content in your while loop.
2. a problem you didn't realise you had: the HTML you're using isn't faithful to the promise that your markup is semantic: that heading should be a heading element (h1, h2, h3, what have you), and as a table, really this shouldn't be `divs` and `p` and `table` at all, this should be a single table, with a heading row, styled as your heading, and then data rows.

So let's rewrite this to something that makes sense both from a PHP and from an HTML perspective:

```
<?php
  ...query your data. Do this first...
  $result = ...;
  if($result isn't empty) {
?>
<table>
  <?php
    echo "<thead><th>$kop</th><th>$description</th></thead>";
  ?>
  <tbody>
  <?php
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      $name = $row['name'];
      $desc = $row['description'];
      echo "<tr><td>$name</td><td>$desc</td></tr>\n";
    }
  ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
<?php } ?>
```

So don't do the querying inside the table, do it first, then if there are results to show, decide whether or not to write the *single* table, generating the dynamic content in the tbody as table rows. And use CSS to style the `thead` cells the way you need.

For that matter, don't use all those inline `style="..."` bits. They're all identical, so you're just needlessly repeating static CSS. Use `class="rowclass"` or whatever name you think is appropriate, and then in your stylesheet or `<style>` block, define

```
.rowclass {
  background-color: ...;
  color: ...;
  ...
}
```

Comment: This one doesn't make my eyes bleed.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 <div id="content_big">
    <div class="content_top_oranje">
        <p class="koptekst">
            <?php echo 'Name';?>
        </p>
        <p style="float:left; margin-left:70%; margin-top:-30px; color:#fff; font-size:11px;font-family:Ubuntu;">
            <?php echo 'Description';?>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="content_mid">
        <?php $kop='algemeen' ;
              $query=$ db->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM ht_forum_categorien WHERE kop = ?");
              $query->bind_param('s', $kop);
              $query->execute();
              $result = $query->get_result();
               ?>
        <table style="width:100%;" border="1" cellspacing="0">
        <?php while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <?php echo $row[ 'name']; ?>
                </td>
                <td style="margin-left:50px;">
                    <?php echo $row[ 'description']; ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
               <?php
              }
        ?>
        </table>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: of course this is still insane HTML, applying all kinds of bad practices.

Comment: I agree, i just gave the solution to his question.

Comment: stackoverflow's also here for future question finders - taking a little more time to not just solve a question's problem, but also explaining what else is wrong, is far more valueable to people who rely on SO.